# Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP

Tags: wcf, service, tcp

I'm trying to host a wcf service (tcp) in a windows service on Windows 2008 x64.

I first made a normal program as host and that works fine.

I then made a windows service with the same config: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

The server installed fine en starts without a problem, but I can't connect to it. 
I think the program isn't loading the config file (exename.config) because myServiceHost.BaseAddresses is empty.

Any idea what could cause this or how I can find the error?

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SlmWcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior" name="SlmWcfServiceLibrary.SlmService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="SlmWcfServiceLibrary.ISlmService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9999/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SlmWcfServiceLibrary.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are using .NET 4 right?  And how are you trying to connect to this? (In a browser or do you have a client config?)

Comment: I'm using .Net 4. I'm not using the browser but a client config.